# Yielding each value from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to assign each value of a list to a variable. I then call that variable from another program.

This is my code:

```
inputList = """["vanilla","vanillas","vanill","vanil","vanila"]"""

def singleListSplitter(inputText):
    try:
        inputList = ast.literal_eval(inputText)
        clean_inputList = [item.strip() for item in inputList]

        #print clean_inputList

        for item in clean_inputList:
            yield item
            print item

    except Exception as e:
        print "Error: ",e


singleListSplitter(inputList)
```

On running the script, I don't see any output in the console with `yield`. The `print` works as expected. What do I need to change to get each individual value?

UPDATE 1

Based on the comments and responses, I tried:

```
value = list(singleListSplitter(inputList))
print value
```

and got a list in response.

What I want really want here are 5 strings (from the list) that I can use elsewhere.

Comment: Your last line of code will return a generator, it should not print anything from within the list.  Can you show how you are iterating through the list?  When I iterate through your generator, I get both the item, and the print statement.

Comment: Yep, the anonymous user above is right. Generator is an example of lazy evaluation (google it, it's helpful in any language). It is not "holding" values like a list, but rather it is "producing" them when asked for next element. Even though it is backed by a list (clen_inputList), it still won't expose the value unless specifically asked to do that.

Comment: I guess the proposed answer of @jbch solves your problem, you "got a list in response" in which you can find the values. Furthermore why you don't just return clean_inputlist in the first place? No need for a generator here if you call list() later on anyways.

Comment: "What I want really want here are 5 strings (from the list) that I can use elsewhere." ... you *can* use those elsewhere, by *using the list*. It's hard to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you use yield in a function, what you have is a generator function.

Generator functions are a bit different from regular function; they do not run when you call them, instead they return a generator object, which is a type of iterator - something you can iterate over, for example in a for loop.

To run the code in the function you need to actually iterate over the generator object.

An easy way to do that is to call `list` on the generator object.

`list(singleListSplitter(inputList))`

But if you are not using the values yielded by your function, there is no reason to use `yield` in the first place, you can just remove it and you'll have a regular function which prints your results.